# Visual Studio 2010 Deploy/Publish a website with Silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

How to deploy/publish a website with Silverlight project in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I have my WCF service in the same web project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way as you would publish any other website, the Silverlight binary file should be included in the ClientBin folder of the Web project.

Answer (score 1):

Build and test (F5) your Silverlight project. When you build and test a Silverlight project, the following files are created in the \bin\debug folder, and Expression Blend tries to open the starting web page.

ProjectName.xap

A compressed archive that includes all the content and resources for the Silverlight application described above. Users download this file on their browsers and run it with the Silverlight plug-in.

Copy the ProjectName.xap file to a folder on a website. For example, if you have Internet Information Services installed, you could copy the .xap file to a virtual directory in the default site that is typically mapped to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot.